# Найти ячейку с датой выше заданной ячейки

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Пытаюсь понять как можно это организовать без добавления лишних скрытых столбцов.
Итак, предположим есть таблица:

```
|  1989/12/3 |         |
|   Ананас   |  фрукт  |
|   Кокос    |  фрукт  |
|  1989/03/9 |         |
|   Персик   |  фрукт  |
|   Капуста  |  овощ   |
```

У меня есть адрес ячейки. Например `А5` со значением `Персик`. Я хочу в ячейку `D1` или любую другую поместить значение первой даты, которая находится над ячейкой `А5`. То есть, искомое значение в ячейке `А4` - `1989/03/9`. Все ячейки с датой в формате даты, а не текста. Соответственно, если бы вместо ячейки `А5` исходная была ячейка `А6`, то ответ был бы такой же, т.к. первая дата над `А6` находится в той же ячейке `А4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько монструозная вышла формула, но работает. Может кому-то пригодится как идея для схожей задачи. Смысл в том, что `MONTH()` будет давать ошибку, если в аргумент подставлять строку, а не дату. На этом и основал прием. Сама формула такая:

```
    =INDIRECT("A"&ArrayFormula(LARGE( IF(IF(IFERROR(MONTH(A:A),"ERROR")<>"ERROR",ROW(A:A))<C$1$,IF(IFERROR(MONTH(A:A),"ERROR")<>"ERROR",ROW(A:A))),1)))
```

Где в `C$1$` вписан номер строки, выше которой ищем первое вхождение даты.

Comment: Совет: использовать INDIRECT только в крайних случаях. Функция летучая (пересчитывается при любом изменении на листе) и медленная

Comment: @vikttur, что значит "летучая"?

Comment: Написано в скобках.

Comment: @vikttur, вы не знаете, откуда взялось это определение?

Comment: Ищите: летучие, пересчитываемые, волатильные, Volatile Functions. В определении функций это одно и то же

Comment: Я понимаю значение "volatile functions", не понимаю, откуда взялось "летучие".

Comment: Точно не скажу... volatile -> изменяются -> запускаются- >летают... У кого-то когда-то возникли определенные ассоциации.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ПРОСМОТР(2;1/--A$1:A5;A$1:A5)
```

Это если прописывать дату в каждой строке.

Если искать дату для указанной строки (в ячейке *C1*):

```
=ПРОСМОТР(2;1/--A1:ИНДЕКС(A:A;C1);A1:ИНДЕКС(A:A;C1))
```

Нелокализованные аналоги функций - *LOOKUP, INDEX, ROW*